# Can MAME4droid emulate a trackball?

Tags: trackball

I see trackballs mentioned in the MAME4droid settings, but only a virtual joystick appears when playing.  Is there support for emulating trackballs via the touchscreen?

Comment: Those settings might be referring to a physical trackball on a phone (like the Nexus One has) rather than an emulated one.

Comment: I had a feeling.  The touchscreen is a natural input analog to the trackball.  I can't believe the trackball isn't emulated yet.